# Reloading Gradle project in eclipse: Cant run project anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Oke so in a sudden case of nostalgia, i switched my eclipse workplace from my working libgdx projects to an older one. After looking through my old stuff i had some problems switching it back, since i didnt import it right. After i got that working, i cant run my libgdx desctop projetc anymore. It says it couldnt load the Spritesheet anymore: After googling a little bit, i was told to make sure the Android asset ordner is linked to the desctop project which it is.

I then noticed that one of the project folders is closed (ive got Project-android,Project-core,Project-desktop and just Project) The ordner project was closed and when trying to open it, it gave me the following error:

> The project description file (.project) for 'Projekt Stella' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

The thing is i made sure that this file is still in the ordner which it is... so now i have no idea how to get this working. Any Ideas?

Edit: The project works fine in Android studio, just not in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: I switched the workplace again to something totally different, then imported the project. Then i deleted the linked assets folder under the desktop project and created it again. This solved the problem and the desktop launcher works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to your build.gradle and do the following in Terminal:

```
gradle eclipse
```

If this doesn't work, create another Gradle project, and copy your sources over.

Comment: How can i open the terminal in eclipse? i spend the last 15min searching and i cant find it ?

Comment: Not in eclipse, in your OS. Use the command prompt, if in Windows.

Comment: Ok so im still not sure what i am supposed to do in the terminal in windows then? sry for the inconvenience, i am not very familiar with the termin and all the commands and what not

Comment: Right, so you need to enter the command listed in my answer, once you have cmd/terminal open in your projects directory.

Comment: Ok so i went into the directory of my project and just wrote "gradle eclipse". Was that the right thing to do? It didnt work, so im probably going to copy everything into a new project.